# onDOMContentLoaded not always fires

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I inject my content script using filtered events instead of manifest content-scripts match rules.

When I navigate to a target page, content script doesn't run always, but only sometimes.  When  it fails to run I refresh the page (sometimes more than once), untill the content script starts.

For simplicity, I don't want to put the code I know is working.  onDOMContentLoaded is not always firing when the filter meets the condition.

```
var filtro = {'url': [
  {hostSuffix: 'somedomain.com', pathPrefix: '/search'}, 
  {hostSuffix: 'somedomain.org', pathPrefix: '/search'}
]};

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(listener, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOcurred.addListener    (listener, filter);
```

So I added onErrorOcurred, to fire when the page fails to load.  But I still missing something, because it doesn't execute every time (but it executes on refreshing the page).

As many other pages, this one trows a lot of error messages to console.  I imagine some of these may prevent onDOMContentLoaded to fire, but I think it should fire onErrorOcurred.  Am I missing some event?

It happens to me in many different extensions and pages when using filtered events.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you give some example pages, so we can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  While looking for a good and easy example, I found onErrorOcurred mistyped (my code up there lacks a 'c').  I'll continue testing, and if it works I'll close this question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You need to check `document.readyState` prior to adding a `DOMContentLoaded` in order to see if the `load` event has already fired.